# can not open parity after remove some old sst files

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

I am using the parity on my mac, due to the limited hardware space, i deleted two olddest sst files under the path

`'/Users/abc/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d/overlayrecent/db'`

now I can't open the parity, what should I do to reopen it again, if I can't open how would i get back my account?

Answer (score 1):

sst files are a part of the database - [article](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/A-Tutorial-of-RocksDB-SST-formats#what-is-sst-static-sorted-table). Unfortunately, this means that you needs to sync parity from scratch. Please remove the database entirely and sync again. If you have very limited space, please take a look at this article - [The Ethereum-blockchain size will not exceed 1TB anytime soon](https://dev.to/5chdn/the-ethereum-blockchain-size-will-not-exceed-1tb-anytime-soon-58a). Also, make sure you are running parity 1.8.6. It contains several optimizations for database